# PhpStorm не обновляются папки

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Поставил PhpStorm после переустановки системы.
Выполняю различные `artisan` команды в Laravel, например `php artisan make:controller SomeController`. Команда выполняется отлично, но при этом папки приходится обновлять вручную
через ПКМ. Раньше всё выполнялось автоматически и не приходилось делать лишних движений. Как это исправить?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727417/12593651](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727417/12593651) но имейте ввиду, что так вы удалите локальную историю всех проектов

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Можете написать это в ответ, я помечу как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ответ на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727417/12593651)

В меню `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart` и выбираем `Invalidate and Restart`

***ВАЖНО:*** *данная операция удаляет всю локальную историю ваших проектов*